# Combining plots produced produced using optim logger

Tags: plot, lua, gnuplot, torch

I have built and MNIST classifier using torch, the results of this are plotted by using optim logger.

When plotting I call `trainLogger:plot()`, where `trainLogger` is `trainLogger=optim.Logger('train.log')`. The same is repeated for the test set. So this gives me two separate plots, is there a way to combine these two logs in one plot?

Answer (score 0):

```
gnuplot
set title "Mean accuracy"
set xlabel "Epochs"
set ylabel "Accuracy (%)"
set yrange [0:100]
plot 'test.log' title "Testing" with linespoints ls 1 linetype 6,'train.log' title "Training" with linespoints ls 1 linetype 7
```

Comment: Consider adding some text to explain your answer to further clarify what/why you are doing.